# Algorithm works in Java but not in C

Tags: java, c, algorithm, arduino, implementation

I have a working implementation of an algorithm in Java but my implementation of the algorithm in C does not work.
The algorithm takes a number and converts it into 2 bytes binary.
Then it converts both bytes separately into numbers again which are then given back to the user.

Implementation in Java:

```
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int bytes[] = new int[16];
    int vals[] = getVals(2000, bytes);

    System.out.println(vals[0]);
    System.out.println(vals[1]);
}

public static int[] getVals(int val, int bytes[]) {

      for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {

        if(val - Math.pow(2, 15-i) >= 0) {

          val -= Math.pow(2, 15-i);
          bytes[i] = 1; 


        }else bytes[i] = 0;

      }

      int val1 = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        System.out.print(bytes[i]);
        System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.println(Math.pow(2, 7-i) * bytes[i]);
        val1 += Math.pow(2, 7-i) * bytes[i];

      }

      int val2 = 0;
      for(int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
        System.out.print(bytes[i]);
        System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.println(Math.pow(2, 7-(i-8)) * bytes[i]);
        val2 += Math.pow(2, 7-(i-8)) * bytes[i];

      }
      int []vals = {val1, val2};

      return vals;
    }
}
```

Output of the Java code: 
val1: 7
val2: 208
which are the right outputs (I calculated them by myself to check them)

Implementation in C for an Arduino (which does not work):

```
#include <math.h>
int vals[2]; 
int bytes[16];
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  getVals(2000);
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) Serial.print(bytes[i]);
  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.println(vals[0]);
  Serial.println(vals[1]);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

void getVals(int val) {

  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {

    if(val - pow(2, 15-i) >= 0) {

      val -= pow(2, 15-i);
      bytes[i] = 1; 


    }else bytes[i] = 0;

  }

  int val1 = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    Serial.print(bytes[i]);
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.println(pow(2, 7-i) * bytes[i]);
    val1 += pow(2, 7-i) * bytes[i];

  }

  int val2 = 0;
  for(int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.print(bytes[i]);
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.println(pow(2, 7-(i-8)) * bytes[i]);
    val2 += pow(2, 7-(i-8)) * bytes[i];

  }
  Serial.println(val1);
  Serial.println(val2);
  vals[0] = val1;
  vals[1] = val2;

}
```

Output of the C code:
val1: 6
val2: 206

-> complete output of the C code:
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
1: 4.00
1: 2.00
1: 1.00
1: 128.00
1: 64.00
0: 0.00
1: 16.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
6
206
0000011111010000
6
206

Could somebody point out what's wrong with the C implementation?
Sadly I can't use the algo in Java cause I need it to run on an arduino.

Thx for helping in advance

PS: this is my first project for an arduino so it is probably just a stupid little mistake which I can't find.

Comment: Your algorithm is a little nuts, as far as I can tell.  You realize that a number in a program is **already** converted to bytes, right?  Why do you do it this way?

Comment: @markspace I dont know if I made my algo clear: I have a number which in binary is 2 bytes large. I have to store each byte on its own on a chip. The function to store something on the chip takes in a number which should be store (1 byte size). My idea is to convert the input number in to binary (2 bytes) and convert each byte into a number which I can than store on the chip.

Comment: Which chip are you talking about (seriously, it matters)?  You realize that if you just store an int to memory the bytes get stored automatically, right?

Comment: EEPROM memory of an arduino nano. the problem is that I can only store one byte at a time, but my number is larger than one byte (2 bytes)

Comment: 1. `int`s are four bytes, so be careful you don't run into issues with overflow.  2. Normally you write all this stuff to a buffer of some sort and then store the buffer in the eeprom.  Some eeproms have "pages" which must be reprogrammed all at the same time.

Comment: @markspace thx but I know for certain that my value will be at max ca. 1000 (altitude of a self made rocket which cant go any higher)

Comment: If it's altitude you should probably be storing a `float`, not an int.  Are you storing perhaps altitude in centimeters?

Comment: No I do it in meters and dont need any more precision. Its just so that I know how high the rocket went when the flight is completed.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go ahead and give an answer here, there's an easier way to do this, which might be easier to get working in C.

```
public class ConvertToBytes {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      final int i = 2000;
      System.out.println( "Low byte:" + (i & 0xFF) );
      System.out.println( "High byte:" + (i>>8 & 0xFF) );
   }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Low byte:208
High byte:7
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: thanks for the implementation.. I am going to try to implement it for the arduino

Comment: This is also the right way to do it in Java.  His Java implementation is horrible.  There's no reason to use pow at all, he just doesn't understand binary representation of numbers

Comment: @GabeSechan what dont I understand? care to explain?

Comment: It's stuff you should have learned in school when the teacher explained radix and binary numbers.

Comment: @sunnyboy4205 How binary numbers are stored in memory, what bitwise operations are, and how to use them

Comment: it seems like my teacher didnt. So maybe you could just tell me what is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: The answer is "several lectures worth of material" so you're going to have to just find a book or something I guess.

Comment: okay thanks I am going to look into it. But the question why the C code doesnt work is still unsolved.

Comment: @sunnyboy4205 Don't expect an answer to that.  Its such a broken way to do it it isn't worth our time.  It's like asking what went wrong with a bridge made out of jello

Answer (score 0):

Your C code is correct (on my PC it gives the result you expect). Also your output seems ok: divide the 2 bytes and check yourself.

```
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
1: 4.00
1: 2.00
1: 1.00

1: 128.00
1: 64.00
0: 0.00
1: 16.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
0: 0.00
```

Rerun and Recheck the result of arduino. If the error persists might depend on the platform.

One thing I can think of is that int variables might be 16 bits so there might be problems summing/subtracting 2^15. I dont think its your case but use unsigned int type or long type.